# From Range to String within .Formula

Tags: string, vba, excel, excel-formula, offset

I might be going at this a little wonky, but I am selecting cell "E2" and going all the way down to the last cell.

I also find the location of a cell containing the word "Subtotal" and return the address. I want the cell next to that one to contain a formula which adds up all the cells from "E2" down to the first empty cell only if the corresponding cell in the "F" column has the word "Yes" typed out in the cell.

It works all the way up to the actual formula, but I am not sure if I have missed a syntax error or some sort.

---

```
Sheets(TextBox1.Value).Select

Dim LastClass As Variant
Range("E2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
LastClass = Cells(Selection.Row, 
Selection.Column).Address(0, 0)

' Finds "subtotal"
Set Subtotal = Sheets(TextBox1.Value).Range("D:D")
Set Subtotal2 = Subtotal.Find("Subtotal")
SubAddress = Cells(Subtotal2.Row, Subtotal2.Column).Address(0, 0)
RR = Range(Subtotal2.Address).Row - 2
Dim RRs As String
RRs = CStr(RR)
SubAddress.Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=SUMIF(F2:F" & RRs & ",""Yes"",E2:" & LastClass & ")"
```

Comment: Lots of assumptions. For instance, what if Selection is several cells? Then your code will fail.

Comment: The code at the top selects just a single cell by selecting the cell at the end of the column (i.e. the last cell with data in it which is exactly what I want). After this point, there is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to having it try to put the formula down one row instead of one column (which wasn't a big deal), I was trying to offset from a cell String rather than from the range which that string represents. All I had to do was put `SubAddress` inside `Range`

```
Sheets(TextBox1.Value).Select

Dim LastClass As Variant
Range("E2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
LastClass = Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column).Address(0, 0)

' Finds "subtotal"
Set Subtotal = Sheets(TextBox1.Value).Range("D:D")
Set Subtotal2 = Subtotal.Find("Subtotal")
SubAddress = Cells(Subtotal2.Row, Subtotal2.Column).Address(0, 0)
RR = Range(Subtotal2.Address).Row - 2
Dim RRs As String
RRs = CStr(RR)
Range(SubAddress).Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=SUMIF(F2:F" & RRs & ",""Yes"",E2:" & LastClass & ")"
```